# How to combine tokens around comments in ANTLR

Tags: parsing, comments, antlr

I am a newbie to ANTLR and using it to develop a parser for an ambiguous language. What I want to do is to some how combine the tokens around the "comments" into one token without using AST.

I am using this simple grammar to illustrate the problem

```
grammar test;

query   
    :     expression+   
    ;

expression
    :   alpha 
    ;


alpha
    : ID
    ;


ID  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*
    ;


COMMENT
    :   '{' ( options {greedy=false;} : . )* '}' {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;
```

Now if we execute it with a simple text "Test{Comments}er" two separate tokens are generated i.e. "Test" and "er". while I want to create a single token out of it. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Jim

Comment: That's the way tokens are handled by a lexer, getting it to work that way will probably require preprocessing. LL/LR parsers aren't designed to handle ambiguous languages, btw, so you might be facing some hard problems in the future.

Comment: Posted here as well: http://antlr.markmail.org/message/nvtzsu6zoh4b3pr4

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but have you tried to do something like this:

```
 ID  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')* COMMENT? ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')* 
;
```

Comment: yeah but then it will become the part of the token; which I don't want actually.

Comment: @Bart, One working form of this rule could be 

ID  :   (('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') COMMENT? )* ;

But this will include the comments in the ID as well which I actually don't want. By the language specs it is possible to have comment any where i.e. in between the alphabets of any single word/Keyword, so I have to get rid of the comments in order to get the word recognized later on in the rules.